# Creation of datetime field in MongoDB not working properly

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to insert a document with datetime in Mongo through python fastapi. My code is as follows. The below code runs inside an API.

```
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/")
mydb = myclient["mydatabase"]
mycol = mydb["customers"]
mydict = {"name": "John123", "address": "Highway 37", "timeCreated": datetime.datetime.utcnow()}
x = mycol.insert_one(mydict)
```

First time I am able to insert the document. Second time when I hit the same API with some other data say different name, I am getting the following error

```
"E11000 duplicate key error collection: lumin_ent_saas.temp_ent_saas_users index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('6346b73e06b6b3e59e7d6cb7') }, full error: {'index': 0, 'code': 11000, 'errmsg': \"E11000 duplicate key error collection: mydb.mycol index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('6346b73e06b6b3e59e7d6cb7') }\", 'keyPattern': {'_id': 1}, 'keyValue': {'_id': ObjectId('6346b73e06b6b3e59e7d6cb7')}}"
```

It is throwing error like object_id already exists but I am trying to insert new data.
But this code works perfectly when run standalone without an API. I am able to insert documents.

I am suspecting there is something wrong with the way Mongodb inserts time. I think it considers same time till I restart the API. Can anyone help here?

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is related to the `timeCreated` field? The error is clearly suggesting that it's a duplicate value for the `_id` field that is problematic.

Comment: That duplicate key error often arises if you try to reuse an object you have already inserted. MongoDB updates the inserted object with the `_id` field. If you try to insert it again the `_id` field is already set and you get a duplicate key error because the index on `_id` is a unique index.